# How to link_to a resource nested under a user when a user may not be signed in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I need a 'Contact' link for both authenticated and unauthenticated users that will send them to

```
new_user_widget_path(current_user)
```

This doesn't work for unauthenticated users of course because there is no current user.  The method I've been using to solve this problem is to have two routes:

```
resources :widgets, only: :new
resources :users do
  resources :widgets
end
```

The only purpose of the first route is to provide redirection in the unauthenticated case, and then redirect that user to the new widget page once he signs in.

```
class WidgetsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def new
    redirect_to new_user_widget_path(current_user)
  end
end
```

This works perfectly well, but I'm curious, has anyone come across a more elegant solution to this problem?

Comment: Why not use a before_filter to make sure they're logged in before they access the new_widget path?

Comment: @bricker It's nested, so the path can't be constructed without a user.  No path, no way to get to the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User is not signed in and but you want proper redirection.  In the view you can do this:

```
new_user_widget_path(current_user || "_")
```

And then add this to application_controller.rb

```
    def stored_location_for(resource_or_scope)
      if path = super
        prefix = polymorphic_path(current_user.class)
        path.gsub!("#{prefix}/_", "#{prefix}/#{current_user.id}")
      end
    end
```

which replaces the underscore with correct ID.

This is implemented on top of Devise's `stored_location_for` method but it can easily be adapted to other authentication setups.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is anything particularly wrong with your approach. An alternative is to have a guest user. In my app, if a user requests a page with needs authentication, I redirect them to the login page, and then redirect them to the page they were trying to go once they log in. If you have a system like this, you can check if the guest id is in the full path and replace it with the now logged in current_user id.

Comment: Yes, that also works.  Does the guest user have any other useful  behavior, or is just for redirection?

Comment: The biggest advantage for me is that the call to current_user never returns null.